# How can i post same page with ajax json

Tags: ajax, json

this is my ajax post code on Default.aspx's source side:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/f_Bul,
            data: "{_sSKodu:'4'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {

                $("#" + div).html(msg.d);
                $("#" + div).show();
            }
        }
        )
```

and this is my function which  is on the Default.aspx.cs

```
 protected void f_Bul(string _sSKodu)
    {
      Select s = new Select(_sSKodu);
    }
```

I want send parameter to f_Bul. but i cant post that data.

where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decorate your method with the [WebMethod] attribute, and it must be static.  It *might* have to be public and return a string as well, not 100% on that though.

```
 [WebMethod]
 public static string f_Bul(string _sSKodu)
 {
      Select s = new Select(_sSKodu);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work with .aspx, so I went to .asmx and this is how I finally got it ot work:

```
   [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class getData : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string finalize(String Number)
        {
            return "{'result':'success'}";
        }
    }
```

I also had to put a script manager on my .aspx page, but it finally worked.

Comment: It probably didn't work for you in the aspx because the web method being called *must* be static.

Comment: I think I tried that, and after spending a while on it, I just moved it out of the .aspx file and got it working, so it could return a json and receive everything as json.